# Cidfonts and mapping

Tags: pdf, character-encoding, fonts

Ok, I've done some research on the subject but as the title indicates I'm no expert. So here's the problem: I'm extracting some text from pdfs using python and the lib pdfminer.

I've only tried documents with latin characters and it works well in most cases, except if the font is not latin/western. The document that bugs me now is using latin characters from a japanese font. Adobe tells me the encoding is `Adobe-Identity`. All I get is the cid of the char and I can't find the cidmap related.

I know I'm not using the right terms, I mean the pdf tells me `cid=3` and I know the char is a space. I've manually written a map for the chars in the range `0x00-0xFF`. Some sources tells it matches the "mac-roman" encoding, other disagrees. Other sources says it match OpenType mapping but I couldn't find anything beyond `0xFF`. And I've got cids >3000.

You can tell I'm very confused, so you're invited to correct my terminology but what I'd want is a map that matches my own but extended for the range `0x0100-0xFFFF`.

ETA: the link to the bugging pdf http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~jtigay/JapanVol.pdf
ETA2: I found this ftp://ftp.oreilly.com/pub/examples/nutshell/cjkv/adobe/aj14.tar.Z the cid2code.txt within the archive is the kind of map I'm looking for. But for all those fonts the cid column seems "shifted" by two: cid1 maps to space.
ETA3: corrected encoding

Comment: Your file [JapanVol.pdf](http://www.sas.upenn.edu/~jtigay/JapanVol.pdf) does not really match your description. The only fonts in there using Adobe-Japan1 are HiraKakuStdN-W4 and RyuminPr5-Regular, and for the former one the embedded glyphs are the digits '0' through '9' and for the latter one only '-', '1', and '3'. There especially is no space glyph embedded for them. Thus, when you say *the pdf tells me cid=3 and I know the char is a space,* you are **not** inspecting glyphs of a font with Adobe-Japan1 CIDs.

Comment: Err, I'm so confused it's really hard to explain my problem. There's a "Times" font in that file too and it is that one which is unreadable. Calibre can't convert it (blank pages), and when I open the doc with pdfminer I only get CIDs instead of unicode chars. I have fully "decoded" what I call a map: when I replace the cid=3 by a space (and so on) I can rebuild the text. And I'm sorry to have so much blank spaces in that map. The greatest CID in that doc is 3013. I don't want to populate the map manually. ETA: it's encoding is Adobe-Identity, you're right

Answer (score 3):

You might be searching for the tables provided in the Adobe Developer Support Technical Note #5078

> [Adobe-Japan1-6 Character Collection for CID-Keyed Fonts](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/font/5078.Adobe-Japan1-6.pdf)

in combination with the background knowledge provided by the Technical Note #5014

> [Adobe CMap and CIDFont Files Specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf).

Unfortunately you have not provided the *document that bugs* you; thus, I cannot check whether the link really is appropriate.

**EDIT**

As you corrected your question and are now asking for [the special-purpose Adobe-Identity-0 ROS](http://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2012/05/sp-ai0-ros.html) *(“ROS” is an abbreviation for /Registry, /Ordering, and /Supplement, which represent the three /CIDSystemInfo dictionary elements that are present in CIDFont and CMap resources)* instead of *Adobe-Japan1-*?, the links above aren't of interest for you anymore. Unfortunately, though, **Adobe-Identity** seems to be the ROS of choice whenever none of the public ROSes is applicable. Thus, there seems to be no generic answer to your question for a map CID to unicode.

Furthermore, the **/ToUnicode** maps of the *Times* fonts in your PDF all look like this:

```
/CIDInit /ProcSet findresource begin
12 dict begin
begincmap
/CIDSystemInfo <<
  /Registry (Adobe)
  /Ordering (UCS)
  /Supplement 0
>> def
/CMapName /Adobe-Identity-UCS def
/CMapType 2 def
1 begincodespacerange
<0000><FFFF>
endcodespacerange
endcmap
CMapName currentdict /CMap defineresource pop
end
end
```

(Here the CIDSystemInfo interestingly differs from that in the PDF font object itself, Adobe-Identity-0.)

According to the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 9.10.3, though,

> it shall use the beginbfchar, endbfchar, beginbfrange, and endbfrange operators to define the mapping from character codes to Unicode character sequences expressed in UTF-16BE encoding.

Thus, there is no usable mapping defined which according to the same spec in combinations with other aspects of those fonts implies that

> there is no way to determine what the character code represents in which case a conforming reader may choose a character code of their choosing.

Comment: Thanks, there's a lot of information there (it's gonna take me some time to explore all this). I edited my post to add the link to the document.