# Strange behaviour of a pdf-to-text conversion

Tags: pdf

I'm trying to convert a pdf document in .txt using `pdftotext` on a linux mint machine. The document is written in english but the output text result something like this:

```
23!,&/$!%+!,#$!AB&017"*&7!"-M')(!-)!gE*X/-&$!$-&23!')!,#$!
(-.$1!/*/-223!(/-&-)E ,$$*!,#-,!,#$!%,#$&!C2-3$&!>'22!($,!
,#$!-9[-0$),!0%&)$&7!S/0#!-!*',/-,'%)!'*!*$$)!')!V'-E
(&-.!Z7!I,!'*!@#',$8*!,/&)1!D/,!)%!.-,,$&!>#$&$!@#',$!(%$
*1!^2-0M!>'22!D$!-D2$!,%!+2'C!,#$ 9'*0!%)!,#$!gE*X/-&$!N(
KO!-)9!,-M$!,#$!#<!0%&
```

Is there an encoding problem? Maybe a wrong option in the command line?

Edit: the problem is the same even if I try to copy a bunch of text from the pdf document end paste it in a text document.

Edit #2: The `Producer` pdf property is: `Mac OS X 10.5.6 Quartz PDFContext`, the encoding for most of the fonts is `WinAnsi` or `MacRoman`. Maybe this can help.

Comment: Not *all* text in *every* PDF is extractable; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21279548/facing-issues-on-extracting-text-from-pdf-file-using-java (summary: yes, it is the encoding, but you don't know which one  is used unless spcified).

Comment: *the problem is the same even if I try to copy a bunch of text from the pdf document end paste it in a text document.* - this normally is a good indicator that trouble is ahead for other programmatic text extraction attempts. And the encoding used is not always as easy as the one I the question @Jongware points to.

Comment: .. to confirm it is indeed impossible to extract meaningful content, you might want to share this PDF.

Comment: @Jongware It is a public document you can find [here.](http://www.tedlandau.com/files/Othello-B%26B.pdf)

Comment: Yup, the fonts *are* encoded (using "Adobe-Identity-UCS"), and there is no further encoding information stored. See mkl's http://stackoverflow.com/a/15727984/2564301 for a longer story. (OT: its binary header reads "Derek's PDF". Interesting--haven't seen that one before.)